# Simplest way to edit value of a single cell in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

What is the simplest way to edit value of a single cell in SQL Management Studio. In the GUI (graphical user interface).

For example:

**1)** I select a row from the table `customer`.

**2)** I want to change in the selected and shown row the value of its `fk_order` column. Which now has value 5 and I want to edit it to have value 8.

In SQL Squirrel this was easy. Just "Make Editable" from context menu and then click the cell and edit value.

How to do that exactly same operation in SQL Server Management studio?
I don't want to write queries this time. I want to learn this way as well. Sometimes this is safer.

Comment: Please just learn how to write an update statement, it's not tricky: `UPDATE Customer SET fk_order = 8 WHERE fk_order = 5 ...` (plus any other conditions to uniquely identify the row)

Comment: In most cases UPDATE statements are better. Sometimes in a running production database SELECTION + manual editing has lower risk than a specific kind of UPDATE statement where a minor mistype would overwrite bunch of critical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries use "Edit top n records" command in SQL management studio.
*However beware, this is not a good practice, use SQL updates, rather do not update records manually, unless at most required.*

Have a look at this video, which shows what I mean,

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzCZunqeVlg

Regards,

N Baua